# Scapy, Socket and 3-way-handshake

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I'm trying to do a pretty weird thing with Python/Scapy/Socket (Linux env). I'd like to manage the 3-way handshake and then go back to the usual "socket" management.

Here is what I did:

```
import socket
from scapy.all import *

pkt = IP(src='192.168.1.2',dst='192.168.1.1')/TCP(sport=12345,dport=44144,flags='S',seq=1000)
SYN = bytes(pkt)

outs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
outs.connect(('192.168.1.1',44144))
outs.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

outs.sendto(SYN, ('192.168.1.1', 0))
raw_buffer = outs.recv(4096)

buffer = IP(raw_buffer)
my_ack = buffer.seq + 1
pkt=IP(src='192.168.1.2',dst='192.168.1.1')/TCP(sport=12345, dport=44144, flags='A', seq=1001, ack=my_ack)
ACK=bytes(pkt)
outs.sendto(ACK, ('192.168.1.1', 0))
```

So far so good, the connection is established. Then I try to use the socket and the created connection with the usual "send" method:

```
outs.send(bytes('AAA','utf8'))
```

At this point I get an error:

```
*** OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to switch back from a RAW_SOCKET to a system handled one. Is that possible in some ways?

Thanks,

Comment: The connection is already estashed when `connect()` returns successful

Comment: No, if the socket is RAW, the 3-way handshake is not sent by the connect.